# Using JSInterface to execute events on the WebView - Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` and some `JavaScript` functions that call some Java code. I have created a `JSInterface` that is attached to this `Webview`. The Java code that is executed via the `JSInterface` function ultimately makes changes to the `Webview` itself.

Without a reference to the `WebView` itself, the function cannot update the `WebView`. It seems odd that my `JSInterface` implementation must contain a reference to the `WebView` to which it is attached! Is there a better way to do this? Some sample code to achieve this looks like so:

1. `WebView`:

   ```
   WebView m = findViewById(R.id.wv);
   m.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   m.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(), "Android");
   ```
2. `JSInterface: 
   public class MyJSInterface {
   @JavascriptInterface
   public void doSomething() {
   //need to update the webview here.
   //first get the Webview.
   MYWebView m = MainActivity.getWebView();  //this is my question. I need the webview that the JSInterface is attached to.
   m.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
   }
   }`

To be able to do this, I need to initialize the `JSInterface` like so: 
`MyJSInterface myji = new MyJSInterface(webViewInstance);`
and then do :
`webViewInstance.addJavascriptInterface(myji, "Android");`

My question:
1. Is this the right way to do this? Is this not circular, i.e., the JSInterface containing an object of the WebView object that calls it?
2. Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No that is not the way it is done (your `MyJSInterface` does not have a `constructor` just for starters...) .

> this is my question. I need the `webview` that the `JSInterface` is
>   attached to.

The answer is simply pass it in to the constructor(you already *found* the `webview`).

> Q1. Is this the right way to do this? Is this not circular, i.e., the JSInterface containing an object of the WebView object that calls it?

*Yes* this is the *right* way to do this. It is **NOT** circular (or recursive if that's what you mean, unless *you make* it so).

> Q2. Are there better ways to do this?

This is the way Google designed it to be. Is there a better way, can only be answered by someone who found a *better way*, and even then it is *subjective*.

> It seems odd that my `JSInterface` implementation must contain a
>   reference to the `WebView` to which it is attached!

Not odd at all, it is a reference to an object you need.

Here's the documented way:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.wv);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Injects the supplied Java object into this WebView.
    // The object is injected into the JavaScript context of the main frame,
    // using the supplied name.
    // This allows the Java object's public methods to be accessed from JavaScript.
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this, webView), "Android");
    //===========================================================================
public class JavaScriptInterface 
{
     Context mContext;
     WebView mWebView;

     // Instantiate the interface and set the context (constructor)
     JavaScriptInterface(Context c, WebView webView) 
     {
         mContext = c;
         mWebView = webView;
     }
//-----------------
    // Show a web page from string
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void loadWebPage(String page) 
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
//-----------------
    // Show a toast from the web page 
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
//-----------------
     //using Javascript to call the finish activity
     @JavascriptInterface
     public void closeMyActivity() 
     {
         finish();
     }
//-----------------
}//class JavaScriptInterface
 //===========================================================================
```

Here is some JavaScript that uses the above code:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Load Web Page" onClick="loadAndroidWebPage('http://www.google.com')" />
<input type="button" value="Close App" onClick="closeMyActivity()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) 
    {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }

    function loadAndroidWebPage(pageURL) 
    {
        Android.loadWebPage(pageURL);
    }

    function AndroidClose() 
    {
        Android.closeMyActivity();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This I get. What if you needed to change the WebView from within the JSInterface (some settings etc.)?

Comment: @Sriram have you *tried* to change something in the `webView` from the interface ? Have you got an error ? There is only a *problem* if there is a *problem* ! I don't see one !

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated the code. My question is whether it is OK to have within the JSInterface implementation, a reference to the WebView to which it is attached. Hope that makes it clear?

Comment: @SriramI updated my answer. Yes it is *o.k.* and *clear* what you want, the fact you think it is *not* shows me your missing a concept somewhere, or have a misplaced apprehension, but I don't what it is, unless you demonstrate it.