# (Chromium for android studio) How to use addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, chromium

In ChromeActivity.Java, I customized some code, but it's not working like webview's addJavascriptInterface I did:

```
import org.chromium.content.browser.JavascriptInterface;
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")

@Override
public void createContextualSearchTab(String searchUrl) {
    Tab currentTab = getActivityTab();
    if (currentTab == null) return;

    Class<? extends Annotation> requiredAnnotation = JavascriptInterface.class;
    currentTab.getWebContents().addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "MyJS", requiredAnnotation);

    TabCreator tabCreator = getTabCreator(currentTab.isIncognito());
    if (tabCreator == null) return;


    tabCreator.createNewTab(
            new LoadUrlParams(searchUrl, PageTransition.LINK),
            TabModel.TabLaunchType.FROM_LINK, currentTab);
}

public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    ChromeActivity context;

    public MyJavaScriptInterface(ChromeActivity activity) {
        this.context = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void closeApp(){
        this.context._closeApp();
    }
}
```

Chromium for android studio source code: https://github.com/kuoruan/Chromium-Android

Comment: `"I customized some code, but it's not working like webview's addJavascriptInterface"` What do you mean by it's **not working** ?

Comment: Right :D not working, cannot call function from javascript:

window.MyJS.closeApp();

Comment: Some thoughts :(1) Maybe object injection into the `JavaScript context` of the `main frame` fails (2) Is `Javascript` enabled on the `mainframe` ? (3) Security (4) Bug in Chromium (5)[example of the *normal* way in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905633/using-jsinterface-to-execute-events-on-the-webview-android/49906427?noredirect=1#comment86829979_49906427)

Comment: Try the [chromium development forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev). Your using a repo of [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/)

Comment: I asked in [Chromium development forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev), but still not get the answers :(

Comment: I think your calling the wrong method `currentTab.getWebContents()...`. You instead should call `currentTab.getContentViewCore()...` for object injection. Worth a try...Also `requiredAnnotation ` is *allowed* to be *null*, to expose all methods.

Comment: Bad news :D in the chromium 65, cannot find addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface anymore :D Now, I dont know how to use Javascript Interface

Comment: Ah. It's changed :D addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface => addPossiblyUnsafeInterface

Answer (score 0):

Since Chromium 65, addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface has been changed to addPossiblyUnsafeInterface

```
mTabModelSelectorTabObserver = new TabModelSelectorTabObserver(mTabModelSelector) {
        @Override
        public void onShown(Tab tab) {
            setStatusBarColor(tab, tab.getThemeColor());
            JavascriptInjector ji = JavascriptInjector.fromWebContents(tab.getWebContents());
            ji.setAllowInspection(true);
            ji.addPossiblyUnsafeInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(ChromeActivity.this), "BEEB", JavascriptInterface.class);

        }
}


public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    ChromeActivity context;

    public MyJavaScriptInterface(ChromeActivity activity) {
        this.context = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void closeApp(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc", duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```